# What's wrong with this self join query?

Tags: sql, self-join

I apologize for such a basic question but I'm new to SQL and can't figure this out somehow. I have a simple table with 3 columns: id, name, and manager_id. Sample entries are:

- 1, Mike, 3
- 2, Kate, 3
- 3, Joe, NULL

I want to return name and the person's manager, e.g. Mike - Joe, Kate - Joe, etc. I'm trying the following code:

```
SELECT
  uno.name AS employee,
  dos.name AS manager
FROM
    `dataset.workers` AS uno
JOIN `dataset.workers` AS dos 
  ON uno.id = dos.manager_id
```

and im getting two sets of names but they don't match (for example, I get Mike - NULL, Kate - Mike). How should I tweak the query to get what I need?

Comment: *`ON uno.manager_id = dos.id`. You were close. The way you read this is "I want to take the `manager_id` from `uno` and look it up in the `id` column of `dos` to get the `name`" which leads to this proper `ON` condition.

Comment: I am surprised you got `Kate - Mike` in your output with your query. I cannot reproduce that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution. You want to use `left join` in case someone doesn't have a manager.

```
select t.name
      ,t2.name as manager
from   t left join t t2 on t2.id = t.manager_id
```

| name | manager |
| --- | --- |
| Mike | Joe |
| Kate | Joe |
| Joe | null |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a1c1be97863351e77a6855ee4dcf4a43&hide=1)

Comment: Thank you @DannySlor! Left join worked like a charm with the code you provided. I tried left join earlier but I was getting too many results (4 for 3 rows in t1) and the names wouldn't match. I realized now what the issue was: In the last line I had "ON t1.id = t2.manager_id" while in fact, I should have had "ON t1.manager_id = t2.id". Thanks @JNevill for catching this and all for suggestions